# How to create a timed quiz in google form

Tags: google-forms, google-classroom, google-form-quiz

I use Google Classroom for my chess club and send out quizzes using Google form. I am trying to find out if it is possible to set up some sort of timer in Google Forms right now. All the answers I can find using google are pretty outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog you can check and try for the implementation on [How to Schedule your Google Forms and Limit Submissions](https://www.labnol.org/internet/schedule-google-forms/20707/). Afterwards, you can just add as a material and attach the link using [Google Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timify.me add-ons. It's easy to use and looks good as well.

Pros:
- timmer shows on the top of the page
- triggers the form to close upon timeout

Cons:
- only paid version allows you to set logo, text, design and webcam tracking
- You can't customize the time countdown section-wise, countdown as a whole  submission

note: you need to configure timify.me with a token from timify.me web app